# how to pass a javascript variable to a java servlet?

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, jsp, servlets

I want to pass a javascript variable to a java servlet. I am developing a web application. This is my html code:

```
<p id="test">Some text</p>
```

And this is what i write in the javascript file:

```
var myVar = document.getElementById('test').innerText;

$.ajax({
    url: 'Test',
    data: {
        myPostVar: myVar
    },
    type: 'POST'
});
```

And then this in the servlet (in the doGet):

```
String result = request.getParameter("myPostVar");
System.out.print(result);
```

And if i run the Test.java to test, it gives me "null". I googled too much but could not find any solution.

Comment: What do you mean "if I run the Test.java to test"? How do you run it?

Comment: You example should work if you pass JavaScript variable to the SERVER.

Comment: Helpful hint, I recommend using ``textContent`` instead of ``innerText`` because the former is W3C compliant and is more universally supported.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you have the `post` method in your ajax and you are trying to get it in the `doGet()` of your servlet.

Use `doPost` or change the method to `Get` in your ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
   throws ServletException, IOException
{
    String myPostVar = request.getParameter("myPostVar");
    // ...
}
```