# pass a javascript variable to a java servlet?

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp, null

I want to pass a javascript variable to a java servlet. I am developing a web application. This is my html code:

```
<p id="test">Some text</p>
```

And this is what i write in the javascript file:

```
var myVar = document.getElementById('test').innerText;

$.ajax({
url: 'Test',
data: {
    myPostVar: myVar
},
type: 'POST'
});
```

And then this in the servlet (in the doGet):

```
String result = request.getParameter("myPostVar");
System.out.print(result);
```

And if i run the Test.java to test, it gives me "null". I googled too much but could not find any solution.

Comment: Same question as this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28100431/how-to-pass-a-javascript-variable-to-a-java-servlet/28104745#28104745 , didnt you get the answer

Comment: Anyway you have to submit the form. Better make an AJAX POST call and on servlet get the parameter. Same as mentioned by San.

Comment: No i did not get the answer. maybe you know some other solution that could work

Comment: Use this into your javascript

 `window.location.href = 'url?parameter=' + myval`

Answer (score 0):

You use doGet instead of doPost

```
type: 'POST'
```

Change it to GET or use doPost in your Java project

Comment: i tried that, but did not work

Comment: Which of the two suggestions did you exactly try? You should change the servlet to doPost(). Parameters in a GET request are passed in the url, not in the request body.